# Programmatically get Tomcat HTTP Connector's maxPostSize in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, server.xml

I am using Tomcat 6 and would like to be able to retrieve the maxPostSize (defined in the HTTP Connector in server.xml) programmatically from within a JSP so that I can know what the max file upload size is.

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you've only one Tomcat service with one connector, then you can access it in Servlet by:

```
int maxPostSize = ServerFactory.getServer().findServices()[0].findConnectors()[0].getMaxPostSize();
```

`ServerFactory` is by the way [`org.apache.catlina.ServerFactory`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/ServerFactory.html).

Note: this tight-couples your code to the Tomcat servletcontainer and your webapp may not be reuseable on other servletcontainers, possibly even not different versions. Consider configuring your own context parameter in `web.xml` with the same value.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>maxPostSize</param-name>
    <param-value>2097152</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then you can access it in Servlet by

```
int maxPostSize = Integer.valueOf(getServletContext().getInitParameter("maxPostSize"));
```

or in JSP by

```
${initParam.maxPostSize}
```

Comment: Sadly in Tomcat 7 the ServerFactory is gone.

Answer (score 4):

In Tomcat7 the ServerFactory class is gone. Apparently one should be able to obtain the Server reference using

```
org.apache.tomee.loader.TomcatHelper.getServer()
```

...which resides in org.apache.openejb:tomee-loader.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for: StandardServer tomcatServer = TomcatHelper.getServer();
  Service[] services = tomcatServer.findServices();